# Excel - Tablas y gráficos desde tabla multidimensional

Tags: excel, hoja-de-cálculo-tabla-dinámica, tabla-dinámica

Quiero obtener pivottables y gráficos de una tabla en excel, pero sólo me obtiene los campos por columnas. ¿Es posible escoger campos por columnas & filas?

Ejemplo:

`(vacía)........Ene.....Feb.....Marzo
 Categoria1.....100......50.....100
 Categoria2.....100......50.....100
 Categoria3.....100......50.....100`

Usando ese ejemplo, ¿cómo hacer un gráfico que, por ejemplo, me muestre en la barra horizontal los meses, y en la vertical de 0 a 100, para que cada color de línea, o de puntos, o de barras, sea cada una de las categorías?

Gracias!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Es posible, desde la versión de Excel 2010 se puede descargar el complemento **Power Query** para la versión 2016 ya viene por defecto se llama **Get & Transform** y se encuentra en la ficha **Datos**

Una vez se tenga activo el complemento se hacen los siguientes pasos:

1. Se selecciona toda la tabla
2. En la ficha **Power query** o la ficha **Datos** se busca el icono **Desde Tabla o Rango** Allí va a salir un cuadro de dialogo con el rango de la tabla y una casilla para indicar si la tabla tiene encabezados. click en **Aceptar**

Se va a abrir el editor de consultas, acá es donde viene la magia :D

3. Seleccione la columna que tiene los datos de categoría y busque un icono que dice **Desdinamizar columnas** en la flecha hay dos opciones. Selecciones **Desdinamizar otras columnas**
4. Listo! En la pestaña **Inicio** click en cerrar y cargar.

Se va a crear una nueva hoja con la nueva data y de esta hace su tabla dinámica y las gráficas que quiera hacer.

En **Power Query** se encuentran muchas herramientas para transformar nuestra data de una forma fácil, le recomiendo comenzar a usar el complemento.

Hice este [video](https://youtu.be/lZA_r5aVetU) hace unos meses explicando algo parecido

Answer (score 0):

estoy probando hacer lo que dices y me resulta sin problemas teniendo en cuenta que uso excel 2016. Pero tuve que habilitar el pivot por que no estaba activo. También seguí este tutorial que sirve mucho de ayuda.

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-a-PivotTable-to-analyze-worksheet-data-A9A84538-BFE9-40A9-A8E9-F99134456576

Espero haberte ayudado! Saludos

Comment: No sirve. Si te fijas, en el ejemplo que pasas todos los datos están en columnas. Cada "tipo de dato" es una columna. No es el mismo ejemplo que yo he puesto. En mi ejemplo verás que la cabecera de todas las columnas es una categoría más (enero, febrero, etc. son "meses" que he de poder listar de la misma forma que puedo listar las categorías de la columna "A").

Comment: Entiendo... disculpas!